# MVC 4.0 Web Application deployment issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, iis

Hi I am stuck in deploying my web application on web server. I have a hosting service which have IIS 7.5 and framework is 4.0. When i try to deploy my application it gives me configuration error and i don't know why it gives me this error.

I have searched a lot yesterday on stack overflow but all the answers did not work for me so that's why I am posting here. My Web.Config file is as follows

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!--
    For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit 
    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
    -->
    <configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="DBConString" value="Data Source=WINCTRL-CHG6UME;
    Initial Catalog=xxxxx; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=xxxx; Password=xxxx" />
    <add key="DBConString" value="Data Source=WINCTRL-CHG6UME; Initial 
    Catalog=CraigsList; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=xxx; Password=xxxx" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CraigsListCNS" connectionString="Data Source=WINCTRL-CHG6UME; Initial 
    Catalog=xxx; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=xxx; Password=xxx" 
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="xxxx" connectionString="Data Source=WINCTRL-CHG6UME; Initial 
     Catalog=xxx; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=xxx; Password=xxx" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>

    <!-- Custom Membership Provider Goes Here -->
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
          <add name="MyMembershipProvider" 
          type="CraigsList.Buisness.CustomMebershipProvider"
               connectionstringname="ApplicationServices"
               maxinvalidpasswordattempts="5"
               minrequiredpasswordlength="6"
               minrequirednonalphanumericcharacters="0"
               applicationName="CraigsList" />
      </providers>
    </membership>


    <!-- Custom Role Provider Goes Here -->
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="MyRoleProvider" type="CraigsList.Buisness.CustomRoleProvider"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." 
      verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" 
      scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" 
      preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" 
      />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." 
      verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" 
      scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" 
      preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0"  
      />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." 
      verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" 
      type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
      preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory 
    type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
  type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

The error I get is at this line

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
```

It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Comment: So, how is your virtual dir configured in IIS?

Comment: I am deploying it for the first time so i have no idea about it

Comment: is MVC4 installed on your web server ?

Comment: Do you have acces to Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager on the server?

Comment: I figured that out it was a foolish mistake. I just did not make the sub-folder a virtual directory at server.